# JQuery search on site loaded in iframe

Tags: jquery, search, iframe

I have a script that load web-sites in iframe. And i want do something:
1) Search in text of this loaded site (for words, for example "contacts")
2) Search only in first 500-600px (or showed page before scrollbar)

Is it really do? And how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless the website in the iframe is of the same domain. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Oh( How about highlighting text? No?

Comment: Afraid not. You'd need to run javascript or insert css to do that, and you can't do that across different domain iframes.